# importlib_metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for streamlit

Tags: python, pyinstaller, streamlit

I was working on a Streamlit Application, While converting it to .exe file using pyinstaller, it is giving this error. How to resolve it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 408, in from_name
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test5.py", line 1, in <module>
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
File "streamlit\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
File "streamlit\version.py", line 33, in <module>
File "importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 909, in version
File "importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 882, in distribution
File "importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 410, in from_name
importlib_metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for streamlit
```

I tried using multiple commands multiple times, but it didn't work our for me. I have checked one post on stackoverflow with same problem as this on pyproj. But the solution didn;t work for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blogpost on how this can be achived:
https://ploomber.io/blog/streamlit_exe/

You need to create a hooks file to copy the metadata

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata

datas = copy_metadata("streamlit")
```

Personally I ran into other issues, but maybe this works for you.